# TypeError: Cannot read property 'BOTTOM' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-sdk

Hello can you help me with this error?

```
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [340,3234] /ui/common/ApplicationTabGroup_Andr.js:1703
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:               MainWallTable.insertRowBefore([0, PendingUploadView, Titanium.UI.RowAnimationStyle.BOTTOM]);
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:                                                                                                  ^
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'BOTTOM' of undefined
```

Thi is my code

```
        WallsArray.MainWall = WallsArray.MainWall.concat(PendingArrayView);
            MainWallTable.insertRowBefore([0,PendingUploadView,Titanium.UI.iOS.insertRowBefore.BOTTOM])
```

Titanium version 11.1.1

Answer (score 0):

`insertRowBefore` doesn't accept an array as a parameter.
https://titaniumsdk.com/api/titanium/ui/tableview.html#insertrowbefore

if is `insertRowBefore(index, row[, animation])` where [] is for optional.

Is this a custom method you've created? Also if you want to pass in a animation parameter it will be `Titanium.UI.TableViewScrollPosition.BOTTOM` (position) or `Titanium.UI.iOS.RowAnimationStyle.BOTTOM` (animationStyle).

Again: https://titaniumsdk.com/api/structs/tableviewanimationproperties.html

Edit: also your code doesn't match the error message.